# Unresolved - Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I have seen several questions and answers to this, but none have been able to resolve it. I am trying to make an AJAX call with jQuery to obtain an IP address.

When running the following code, I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function` in the console.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Ready!');

  const fetchIp = (callback) => {
     $.ajax({
        url: `https://api.ipify.org?format=json`,
        method: "GET"
     })
     .then(res => {
       console.log(res);
       callback(res);
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
});
```

A common issue seems to be when using the `slim` version of jQuery. However I am currently using the full version, so I don't think that is the issue.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I also tried using `jQuery.ajax`, but that has the same result. I have tried installing jQuery from npm as well, but that didn't work either. I must be missing something terribly obvious, but I can't seem to spot it.

For context I'm using Express EJS, and I'll have to make a few more API calls after this (getting latitude and longitude based on the IP), and plan to add them into a few more `.then()`.

Pretty new with AJAX so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Where and how you are calling the fetchIP function?

Comment: Are you trying to use `$.ajax` in Node or in the browser? In the browser, using `$.ajax` after the `<script>` tag you show works fine. Are you certain you’re not loading two versions of jQuery somewhere?

Comment: Open your console and log $ and jQuery to find out what they contain. Also check if cors is blocking the script from loading. If all else fails, just download the script and include it from your own server.

Comment: provide the full error message from JS Console pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a second jQuery script running on the page, hidden in a partial where it should not have been.